# at command for linux job not working from php

Tags: php, linux, shell, at-job

I have a script `.sh` with a [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) command in it:

```
curl --digest "http://xxxxxxx.xxx/mail.php?email=xxxx@xxx.xx";
```

from terminal this works good :

```
./script.sh #(mail arrives in my box)
```

from php this works good:

```
shell_exec('./phpsc.sh');  // (mail arrives in my box)
```

from terminal this works good:

```
 at -f phpsc.sh now + 5 minute 
 # (job created, mail arrives in my box after 5 minutes)
```

from php this won't work:

```
shell_exec('at -f phpsc.sh now + 5 minute'); //:( :(
```

even when I put `at` command in script and run the script from php the `at` command it will be ignored :(

Comment: The difference between phpsc.sh and script.sh is not clear - but maybe start by adding a path to the `at -f _add_path_here_/phpsc.sh now + 5 minute`

Comment: yes i did put the full path but nothing :( :(

Answer (score 2):

i have find the solution,

i removed **www-data** from **/etc/at.deny** and now 'at' comand works fine from php (sell_exec)

Answer (score 0):

I know its sometimes necessary to use `source` to invoke environment variables.

Here it what you should try (adapt if you use something else than [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh)):

```
shell_exec('source ${HOME}/.kshrc ; at -f phpsc.sh now + 5 minute');
```

Comment: sorry but i did not understand what i have to do :( :(

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS 7, I had to add 'apache' at /etc/at.allow.